# Помогите сравнить 2 массива Python Numpy

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, сравнение

Имеется тренировочная задача, в которой надо создать массив, который получает результат поэлементно `True`, если четные элементы 1-го массива больше 2-го и `True`, если нечетные элементы 2го больше элементов первого. В противном случае возвращать `False`.

Пример массивов и результата:

```py
n = [7, 3, 5, 9, 2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 0]
m = [2, 8, 6, 7, 1, 3, 2, 9, 5, 1]
res = [ True, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, True, True]
```

Решаю задачу с помощью функций `np.arange` и `np.where`, пока код вот такой :

```py
res = np.where(
                   np.arange(len(n)) % 2 == 0, 
                   n > m, 
                   m > n
         )
```

Результат выдает неверный

```
array([ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False])
```

Скорее всего потому что надо 2 условия: одно про четность индексов массива n, второе - про нечетность индексов массива m, но как 2 условия записать одновременно я не могу понять.

Помогите, пожалуйста, как тут сделать чтобы выполнялось 2 условия.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так у вас `n` и `m` - это обычные списки, поэтому их сравнение работает не так, как вы думаете:

```py
n = [7, 3, 5, 9, 2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 0]
m = [2, 8, 6, 7, 1, 3, 2, 9, 5, 1]
print(n > m)
# True
```

Чтобы получить нужный результат, нужно взять именно `numpy.array`, тогда сравнения будут работать правильно - поэлементно:

```py
n = np.array([7, 3, 5, 9, 2, 5, 4, 8, 9, 0])
m = np.array([2, 8, 6, 7, 1, 3, 2, 9, 5, 1])
print(n > m)
# [ True False False  True  True  True  True False  True False]
```

Остальной код правильный и результат работы `np.where` теперь будет правильный.

Comment: Точно. Спасибо большое.